# Can't log in with Symfony2

Tags: security, symfony

security.yml:

```
providers:
    main:
        entity: { class: Tg\UserBundle\Entity\User, property: username }
encoders:
    Tg\UserBundle\Entity\User: sha512
```

In my manager during registration I set the password:

```
    $encoder = $this->encoder->getEncoder($user);
    $raw = $user->getPassword();
    $salt = $user->getSalt();
    $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($raw, $salt);

    if (!$encoder->isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt)) {
        throw new \Exception('Password incorrectly encoded during user registration', 428);
    } else {
        $user->setPassword($encoded);
    }
```

In my User entity I have the basic salt on construct:

```
$this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
```

I receive error on default login template:

> The presented password is invalid.

Wtf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly an answer (i can't figure out why you r example is not working). But I'm using sha512 base64 encoded and this setup is working fine for me:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Acme\HelloBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: sha512
            encode_as_base64: true
            iterations: 10
```

Salt initialization in `User` class:

```
$this->salt = base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That didn't solve it, but using your salt made me change the length of my salt column, and alas, there was the error, the lengths of password was too small. Thanks for leading me to the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this error as well.  You need to make sure you password field can support the sha512 hash size.  I think the tutorials make the password field default to a size of 40.  You need to extend this to a larger size (125).